# What java android files should I not upload to my SVN Server?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, svn, build

I just setup SVN for my java Android project through SubEclipse. Can anyone advise me on which files I should not upload to the repository? Just like in Objective C I have my build files in a separate folder, I still don't know how the build system in Java organizes files and what is considered "build" files.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would leave out anything in the following directories:

- /bin
- /gen
- /libs

You will need to check in the following files only if you want to include your Eclipse project settings:

- /.settings
- /.externalToolBuilders
- .classpath
- .project
- default.properties

Comment: /libs should be checked in if there isn't something like maven or ivy to handle the jars there.  Downvote on checking in the classpath

Comment: @Woot4Moo I disagree with the generalization on .classpath.  It's OK to check in .classpath if **everything** in them is relative to the project.  If you use any non-relative references then avoid it. I agree with /libs

Comment: @Chris I have yet to see everyone's class path match when there are more than 3 developers :)

Comment: Can we ignore bin/gen folders for standard library projects like facebooksdk and google play services?